Does a vector database maintain pre-vector chunked data for RAG systems?
I believe that when using an LLM with a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) approach, the results retrieved from a vector search must ultimately be presented in text form. Otherwise, the prompt would just contain a series of numbers (vectors), which would be meaningless. I assume that the pre-vector chunked data needs to be stored somewhere within the vector database. Is this usually maintained within the vector database itself?


I assume that the pre-vector chunked data needs to be stored somewhere within the vector database. Is this usually maintained within the vector database itself?

Yes. Code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77843105/395857
